# Expanding page navigation splitted Query result

Tags: php, sql, navigation

I have the results of my query getting split into pages. That is done using the following code:

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * 10; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles where hoofdrubriek = '".$rubriekpage2."'  ORDER BY bedrijfsnaam LIMIT $start_from, 10"; 
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 

echo a result....

}

?>
```

Next up is creating the navigation for the seperate pages:

```
<?php

if(mysql_num_rows($rs_result)!=0){

?>

<br /><div style="margin-left:200px;width:300px;text-align:center;background-color:">Pagina's:<br clear="left"> 


<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(bedrijfsnaam) FROM profiles where hoofdrubriek = '".$rubriekpage2."'"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 10); 

if ($total_pages>10) $total_pages=10;
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a style=\"float:none;display:inline-block;color:white;width:22px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;background-color:#483435;margin-left:4px\" href='".$plaatsnaam7.".php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 

}; 
?>
```

All works great so far, no problems there. However: I am limited to 10 pages and that's it. Of course I can alter the number to say 25, but what I would really like is a previous and next button beside my 'numbers' navigation. If there are more than 10 pages, put a next button on the right that will display the next 10 digits and so on...

I've been Googling all evening, but haven't come up with a single decent result, tutorial or anything like that. Any of you guys in the mood to lend me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: So just to get this straight, are you asking for how to search google for "php mysql pagination tutorial" or for lessons in how to read the multitude of excellent tutorials that that search returns?

Comment: @Captain Payalytic Well Captain Sarcastic, that search actually turns up some nice tutorials, thanks, my searches clearly weren't enough 'to the point'.

Comment: So obviously ou required the former, help in how to use Google.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the current page is the not the first, if the next 10 pages are valid, and display the previous, next, and page links if so.

```
 function page_link($i) {
      echo "<a style=\"float:none;display:inline-block;color:white;width:22px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;background-color:#483435;margin-left:4px\" href='".$plaatsnaam7.".php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
  }

  function page_next($i){
       // link to page $i with arrow right
  }
  function page_prev($i){
      // link to page $i with arrow left
  }
 $s = $_GET['page'];
 if ($s > 1) page_prev($s - 1);
 for  ($i = $s; $i * 10 < $total_count && $i < $s + 10; $i++) { 
      page_link($i);
 }
 if (10 + $i * 10 < $total_count) page_next($i+1);
```